# How do I use mocks in some cases but not others in QuarkusTest?

Tags: dependency-injection, quarkus

I have two classes in a Quarkus application, let’s call them Service A and Service B. Service B is a dependency of A. When I test ServiceA, I want to mock ServiceB. When I test ServiceB, I want to test the real Service B.

I've created a MockServiceB class following [this guide on quarkus.io](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing). If I put it in my /test directory, my ServiceATest will properly grab the mock. But so will my ServiceBTest class. How can I selectively inject mocks to different classes? Better yet, can I selectively use different mocks for different methods?

(I tried falling back to using Mockito, but it doesn't seem to work with Quarkus & QuarkusTest, unless I'm mistaken.)

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceA {
    @Inject
    ServiceB serviceB;

    public int giveMeANumber() {
        serviceB.getNumber();
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceB {

    public int getNumber() {
        // does the real work;
        return 1;
    }
}


@QuarkusTest
class ServiceATest {
    @Inject
    ServiceA serviceA;

   @Test
    public void shouldReturnNumber() {
        int number = serviceA.giveMeANumber();
        assertEquals(1, number);
    }
}

@Mock
@ApplicationScoped
class MockServiceB extends ServiceB {
    @Override
    public int getNumber() {
        // don’t do the real work
        return 1;
    }
}

@QuarkusTest
class ServiceBTest {

    @Inject
    ServiceB serviceB;

    @Test
    public void shouldGetNumber() {
        int number = serviceB.getNumber();
        // uses the mock, I don't want it to
        assertEquals(1, number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently this not supported out of the box, but that could change in the future

Comment: Okay thanks. I think this might be a dealbreaker for me. Might need to put Quarkus back on the shelf for now.

Comment: The ability to do this might be closer on the horizon rather than further. I would suggest to keep an eye out for it

Comment: Cool. I’ll build in a way that I can migrate to quarkus without too much trouble

Comment: @geoand found [this ticket](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5394) for tracking this issue, are there any others?

Comment: That is the one @jordanpg

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Quarkus 1.4, you can use Mockito mocks for normal scoped CDI beans (so `@ApplicationScoped` can be mocked, `@Singleton` can't) using the `@InjectMock` annotation.
See [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/ff6f5482096c9682baa5bca15d8f88ac11e6d55e/docs/src/main/asciidoc/getting-started-testing.adoc#72-mocking-using-quarkusmock) for documentation and [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/96db1d725d689f441bcf674741ae974a3cf2c90b/integration-tests/injectmock/src/test/java/io/quarkus/it/mockbean/GreetingResourceTest.java#L16) for an example usage.