# Quarkus. Testing with spy in the integration test

Tags: integration-testing, quarkus

I see that there is [some](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#mock-support) [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450439/how-do-i-use-mocks-in-some-cases-but-not-others-in-quarkustest) when it comes to mocking/spying in `Quarkus`.

The question is, how would I do something similar to this with the means that Quarkus provides? To spy on `restClient` and see how many times it was invoked.

```
    @QuarkusTest
    public class MyResourceTest {

      @Inject
      @RestClient
      MyRestClient restClient;

      @Ineject
      SomeServiceThatCallRestClient someService;

      @Test
      public void test() {
         restClientSpy = spy(restClient);

         someService.doSomething();     // it would call the restClient    

         assertThat(clientSpy.times(), is(equalTo(1)));

      }
```

Comment: You can't do that unfortunately. Mind opening a feature request please?

Answer (score 0):

What you could is to create an ApplicationScoped Beam as a wrapper for your restClient.

Example:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class RestClientWrapper {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    protected MyRestClient restClient;

    public String  getString(long stringId) {
        return restClient.getString(stringId);
    }
}
```

Then, your test would be:

```
@QuarkusTest
public class MyResourceTest {

  @InjectSpy
  protected RestClientWrapper restClient;

  @Inject
  protected SomeServiceThatCallRestClient someService;

  @Test
  public void test() {

     someService.doSomething();     // it would call the restClient    

     Mockito.verify(restClient).getString(anyLong());
     Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(restClient);
  }
```